# Display null characters in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, display, putty, special-characters

A program running on a server sends text data delimited by a null character (`^A`, SOH). When I access that server via PuTTY, PuTTY skips the control characters; **it does not display them at all** on its "terminal" screen. This makes the data very hard to interpret, as it is impossible to distinguish where one field ends and the next begins. If I open PuTTY's session **logfile** in a text editor, **all** the control characters are visible. Is there any way I can configure PuTTY to **display** *something* when it receives a control character? (The messages are in the standard [FIX protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange), if anyone is curious.)

How PuTTY shows the message:

14=200015=USD17=80100009620=022=129=130=O31=158.92788132=320037=000000000038=039=140=2

How vi shows the same message: (In vi, `^A` shows up in blue, making it easier to read.)

**^A**14=2000**^A**15=USD**^A**17=801000096**^A**20=0**^A**22=1**^A**29=1**^A**30=O**^A**31=158.927881**^A**32=3200**^A**37=0000000000**^A**38=0**^A**39=1**^A**40=2

If I replace the nulls with spaces, it is understandable at a glance:

14=2000 15=USD 17=801000096 20=0 22=1 29=1 30=O 31=158.927881 32=3200 37=0000000000 38=0 39=1 40=2

Comment: Can't you use `tr` or `sed` to make them visible before feeding to the editor? Vim could also filter the input ...

Comment: I would ideally like to see them in the shell without having to use an editor. I can open the log files with an editor and null chars are visible so the messages are readable, however there is a significant delay from when a message is sent and when it is logged, and I often need to immediately interpret messages as they come in...

Comment: `^A` is not the null character, the null character is `^@`.  `^A` is the first character after the null character.

Comment: So I have found this is impossible without modifying the program. 001 is the SOH character is not displayed in any character set. In terms of modifying the logs the tr command did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the unprintable charaters with something readable.

### before

```
$ find  -print0
../03.lines./04.lines./02.lines./01.lines$
```

### after

```
$ find  -print0 | sed 's/\0/  /g'
../  3.lines./  4.lines./  2.lines./  1.lines$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **stdbuf** (from **coreutils**) and **tr**:

```
$ while true; do printf "ASDF\001"; sleep 0.5; done | stdbuf -o0 tr '\001' ' '
ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ...
```

*Note: stdbuf is not needed when replacing with a newline, ie `tr '\001' '\n'`*

Or, use **awk/gawk**

```
$ while true; do printf "ASDF\001"; sleep 0.5; done | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\001"}; {printf "%s ", $0}'
ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ASDF ...
```

This works irrespective of terminal. See [What is buffering...](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for more information.